# Gradle builds on Github Actions hangs

Tags: java, gradle, github-actions, compose-desktop

I am building my Jetpack Compose Mac OS app using Github Actions.

Sometimes (most of the times), when gradle executes `./gradlew createReleaseDistributable` after a while the build hangs and keeps shows the following trace indefinitely causing the build to timeout. In the few cases the build succeeds it takes ~6minutes.

The stacktrace:

```
2022-11-25T13:29:31.666+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Execute container callback action' started
2022-11-25T13:29:31.666+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Execute container callback action'
2022-11-25T13:29:31.667+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Execute container callback action' started
2022-11-25T13:29:31.667+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Execute container callback action'
2022-11-25T13:29:31.667+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Execute container callback action' started
2022-11-25T13:29:31.667+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Execute container callback action'
2022-11-25T13:29:31.668+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Execute container callback action' started
2022-11-25T13:29:31.668+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Execute container callback action'
2022-11-25T13:29:31.668+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Execute container callback action' started
2022-11-25T13:29:31.668+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Execute container callback action'
2022-11-25T13:29:31.672+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Execute container callback action' started
2022-11-25T13:29:31.673+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Execute container callback action'
2022-11-25T13:29:31.673+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Execute container callback action' started
2022-11-25T13:29:31.673+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Execute container callback action'
```

Things I tried:

- Using the latest gradle version (7.5.1)
- Setting gradle ram to -Xmx10240m
- Disable the daemon deamon (from project/gradle.properties)

no luck. sometimes the build goes by successfully which makes this even weirder.

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the party, but maybe it could be helpful for somebody.

I was experiencing the same issue and by analyzing the logs I found out that the build was stuck at the codesign part.

By replacing the manual import of the certificates with this action: https://github.com/Apple-Actions/import-codesign-certs, the build is not stucking anymore.